# What connection do Facebook and GMail use for messaging?

Tags: gmail, chat, instant-messaging

I'm building a web app that needs to be able to immediately receive messages from the server (kind of an instant message chat).
I noticed Facebook and GMail have messaging in a browser and do not require any browser plug-in for that.
What do they use?

I know websockets doesn't work when relying through a proxy?
Is there another good method?